# drawing a frame with a resolution dimensions in OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I want to check my resolution by drawing a frame with a resolution dimensions and see the drawn frame, in OpenGLES 2.0 emulator (at PC).
I draw a with line_strip on these coordinates:

```
-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
-1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
```

By this function:

```
glDrawArrays ( GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 5 );
```

and I see only the right and the upper sides, and don't see the left and the lower sides. It seems like they are out of the screen (if I draw these sides not from -1.0f, but a little higher i.e -1.0f + 1 / screen_width then I can see all the sides).
Can you explain me please, why I don't see all the sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is rounding the values. The values that present screen borders do not present a specific pixel but a value between pixels. For your specific case it would seem you have used "ortho" method to define your borders on interval [-1, 1]. Imagine your view consisting of only 4 pixels as 2x2: In this case you still have borders defined on interval [-1, 1] but the actual pixel positions would be `(-.5, -.5), (-.5, .5), (.5, -.5), (.5, .5)`. Now all things considered when drawing lines representing the border you will have only 3 pixels filled (2 lines). Which of them will be filled depends on rounding the .5 floating value to integer value: If .5 is rounded to 1 you can expect upper left part to be filled, in other case the bottom and right (note that terms "left,right,up,down" depend on internal buffer structure, not what you see on the display).

So to fill the correct pixels with the line you would need something like this (left part only):

```
-1 + (2/bufferWidth)*.5
```

To break it down: -1 is the border value; 2 is the interval width defined in your "ortho" (right - left); bufferWidth represents the number of pixels; (2/bufferWidth) is the pixel width; .5 to get the center of the pixel.

To solve this issue in your case it might be enough to simply set the line width to 1.5.

Comment: unfortunately the only supported line width is 1.0, but now i understand the issue, and the calculation will help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: You know, you can always change the "ortho" during the pipeline even if you need it for a single draw call. Just set it to (0,width,0,height), draw the lines at specific pixels and then swap back to [-1,1].